# How to set up a not-local svn-server?

Tags: svn, visualsvn

Hi i would to know how to se up a svn server? Now, i'm using VisualSVN a TortoiseSVN, but i don't know what are the directories "branch" "trunk" "tags".
Can anyone explain me how it works?
I read the svn book and many sites articles about it but i don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to setup a SVN server is a very different question than what "branch", "trunk" and "tags" are used for.

A SVN server can be setup using a lot of different methods: Apache (with dav_svn), svnserve over SSH or countless others.

Take a look at the [svn-book's chapter on server setup](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.html) for more information.

If you need more information on SVN in general, [the entire book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html) might be of use to you.

To get a quick overview of SVN, branching and tagging, take a look at the following Wikipedia articles:

- [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_(software)), with the section on [branching and tagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_(software)#Branching_and_tagging).
- [Branching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_(software))
- [Tagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_tag)

Answer (score 2):

theses are default directory optionally created with VisualSVN when you setup a repository, this is a longtime convention for repository structure:

*(disclaimer: I'm not svn lawyer)*

**trunk**: will contain your development mainline, you develop new features here

**branches**: are sidelines for your development, branches are generally created from the trunk or another parent branch. You generally use branches to develop new features before merging them in the trunk, or to do maintenance tasks

**tags**: is just a place to put your release revision for reference, you can't (by default) overwrite branches created into tags

main thing: in svn all theses are directory, you can branch any existing branch to any other location (tags is restricted), and you can merge them later (with more or less pain) into another branch

theses are all generic descriptions, and there is various usage pattern of branches, if you need more information, thank you for being more precise.

edit: also I recommend to take the time to read [chapter 4 Branching and Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am a little uncertain whether your question concerns setting up an SVN server or whether you are more concerned with the structure of your project's evolution (setting up your trunk and various branches).

However, consider the possibility that you might *not* want to expend the time and energy needed to master SVN server management - especially if you still have this many questions after reading the documentation.  After considering various options for our source control management strategy, we decided to use a third-party SVN-hosting service.  We ended up using BeanStalk (http://www.beanstalkapp.com) along with Tortoise SVN and Visual SVN.  I am not associated with BeanStalk but I can tell you that, for $15 a month, we've been very happy with the results.  Note that we manage a web server farm so server availability was not at all an issue - only time and expertise - and we still decided to go to an outside vendor.